# how to use query to find max parameter in microsoft access

Tags: sql, ms-access

i have table with 2 columns - "employee" , "salary".
i am trying to get the employee with the highest salary.
i have tried a lot of things on design view but it doesnt working.

Answer (score 4):

If you want *all* employees with the highest salary, then you can do:

```
select top 1 t.*
from t
order by salary desc;
```

MS Access includes ties with you do `top 1`.

If you want only one employee, then you can include another sort key:

```
select top 1 t.*
from t
order by salary, employee desc;
```

This behavior is explained in the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-24f2a47d-a803-4c7c-8e81-756fe298ce57):

> The TOP predicate does not choose between equal values. In the
>   preceding example, if the twenty-fifth and twenty-sixth highest grade
>   point averages are the same, the query will return 26 records.

Comment: I didn't know that Access' `TOP` implicitly uses `WITH TIES`.  It would be nice to see a documentation reference.

Comment: can you explain how to do it on the Access "design view"?

Comment: There are a few ways of doing it, @chenporcilan: you could copy the code into the SQL view in design mode, and then switch back to design view to see what it does. This method is only really useful if the fields are all exactly named correctly etc. Otherwise, to get the 'top x' part of the query, in design view there's a drop down for "Return:" which defaults to All, and you can enter a new value there (eg top 1). Sorting you can do using the sort option against each field you bring into your query.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is using a subquery. Assuming your table is called tblSalTest:

qrySalMax would get the max of all the salaries (only returning the Salary field):

```
SELECT Max(tblSalTest.Salary) AS MaxOfSalary
FROM tblSalTest;
```

qryFinal uses qrySalMax to select the correct records from tblSaltest.

```
SELECT tblSalTest.Employee, tblSalTest.Salary
FROM tblSalTest, qryMaxSal
WHERE (((tblSalTest.Salary) In (select MaxOfSalary from qryMaxSal)));
```

Or I suppose

```
SELECT tblSalTest.*
FROM tblSalTest INNER JOIN qryMaxSal ON tblSalTest.Salary = qryMaxSal.MaxOfSalary;
```

@Gordon's answer is better in my opinion.